# How do I setup my wifi & pppoe and use them asus x550

Tags: wireless, pppoe

I have an laptop asus x550 and want to connect to WiFi or pppoe but don't know anything about both of them and fully beginner and need help to step by step setup them.
I use ubuntu 13 last version
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/971809)(Mark yourself affected) in the wifi driver, there are some [workarounds](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558). The one that worked for me:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

This creates a file `asus_nb_wmi.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d` that will load `asus_nb_wmi`, with the parameter `wapf=1` that will be activated at next reboot.

**Note**: <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> will not work

---

The following is excerpt from: [[SOLVED] Fix : Asus WiFi Disabled (Hard-blocked), Fn+F2 won't work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558), just in case the aforementioned workaround does not work for you.

> Until this issue is fixed with newer updates, you may use "xbindkeys"
>   tool to set a hotkey (can be a single key or a key-combination) of
>   your choice to toggle the WiFi enabled/disabled.
>
> This is how -
>
> A. Create a Script to do it smartly :
>
> 1) First, we create a script (for ease of use, and so that we can
>   toggle it on/off using the same hotkey) - Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to toggle the wireless blocked/unblocked

# index no. of phy interface IFACE=`rfkill list all | grep phy | cut -c 1`

# WiFi block state 0=active, 1=blocked BLOCKED=`rfkill list all | grep -iA1 phy | grep -ic soft.*yes`

if [ $BLOCKED -eq 1 ]; then     rfkill unblock $IFACE

else    rfkill block $IFACE fi
```

> Copy-paste the contents of the above box in a text file and save this
>   file in your Home directory with the name - "wifitoggle.sh". Make sure
>   the first line is (without double quotes) "#!/bin/bash" and last one
>   is "fi".
>
> 2) Make the script executable by running the following command in a
>   terminal - Code:

```
chmod +x wifitoggle.sh
```

> 3) Run the following command to Create a symlink to this script in
>   /bin directory - Code:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/wifitoggle.sh /bin
```

> Now proceed to binding it with a hotkey as follows -
>
> B. Bind the Script with a HotKey of your choice :
>
> 1) Install xbindkeys-config (a GUI frontend to xbindkeys - the program
>   that captures and binds hotkeys with commands) - Code:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
```

> 2) Create a default config file for it (else it would crash on key
>   capture step) - Code:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

> 3) Run the program from terminal or "Alt+F2" (because it does not
>   create a launcher in Unity dash) - Code:

```
xbindkeys-config
```

> let the terminal running in the background.. In the GUI box that
>   opens, 3 example shortcuts are already present. You may leave them.
>
> 4) Click on "New" button at the bottom of the GUI.
>
> 5) In the right hand pane of the GUI, fill in a suitable name in the
>   "Name" field, e.g. "Toggle Wifi"
>
> 6) Click on "Get Key" button. This will open a tiny blank box doing
>   nothing but waiting for your input.
>
> 7) Press the desired key (or key combination) that you want for
>   toggling Wifi on/off. For example, "F3" key (as it remains mostly
>   unused). The tiny box will disappear and the key will be recorded.
>
> 8) In the "Action" field, type this - Code:

```
/bin/bash /bin/wifitoggle.sh
```

> 9) Click on "Apply" button and test the hotkey to see if it works as
>   expected.
>
> 10) Click on "Save & Apply & Exit" to save the new hotkey to the
>   default file and exit.
>
> From now on, as soon as you will press this key or the
>   key-combination, the wifi will change its state from On to Off, or Off
>   to On.
>
> The Fn key doesn't seem to be noticed by any key capture program I
>   could find (probably that's why it is considered "Hardware Switch"),
>   so it's not possible to use it yet.
>
> Once more, I'd request anyone who needs this workaround to submit a
>   bug report against the problem, or add themselves to the "Affects Me"
>   list, and point to this thread as a possible workaround.
>
> The stronger it gets reported, the sooner we'll get it fixed, thus not
>   requiring such crude workarounds.

---

Thansk to fossfreedom, and seth for the research!

**Workaround(s)**

- [[SOLVED] Fix : Asus WiFi Disabled (Hard-blocked), Fn+F2 won't work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558)

**Bug**

- [Bug #971809 “168c:0032 Wifi connection unstable -- Atheros AR948...” : Bugs : “linux” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/971809)

Answer (score 0):

If you can see a wifi symbol on the op panel on your desktop then click it and select the coonection you want to connect. If you are not able to see wifi networks then plaese follow the following steps:

1. Click on the first icon in unity (menu panel on left hand side)
2. Type **Additional Driver**
3. Run the application.
4. If everything goes well then you might be able to see your wireless card in the application.
5. Select you card and then click on the Activate button at the right hand bottom side.
6. Restart and enjoy wireless.

For more info click below:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/jockey-gtk/